# Punchout Scenario possibility in php

Tags: php, b2b

I am implementing punchout in PHP so I have a system ABC where companies can create their orders (How to import supplier catalog into my system?) and after that, the ABC Admin will process their order, means will send Purchased Order(PO) to the supplier. Is this possible to create a cart on our own system without any redirection to the supplier site and then put the PO to the supplier? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Please give more details and double check in whether your question is on topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

If supppler catalog companies provide the api for import. then it will possible. other than you will need to tracking the catlog of suppler.